# How do I install old programs saved from Windows?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, permissions

I have been trying to install programs onto my newly loaded Ubuntu system and so far I have found that they belong in the `etc` folder, but of course I do not have permissions for this as Linux has set up their systems to be like this. How can I bypass this within the terminal?

I'd like to install old programs I saved from my previous system (Windoes 10) like VLC, etc onto my Linux system. Is there a better (and safer) place to install them than the `etc` folder or should I just redownload them completely?

Comment: to write to `/etc` you can use `sudo`, but that is not the place to install programs. Please tell us what you are actually trying to achieve so we can help you properly without breaking your system

Comment: Programs haven't belonged in the `/etc` folder since about 1980. If you want to install software for all user, either use the Ubuntu package manager or install the software into `/usr/local` or `/opt`, that's what they're for.

Comment: Basically I'd like to install old programs I saved from my previous system (WIn10) like VLC, etc onto my Linux system. Is there a better (and safer) place to install them than the etc folder or should I just redownload them completely?

Comment: @Enzo You should download native Linux version of the applications whenever possible.

Comment: @Enzo old programs you saved from your Windows 10 system **will not run under Linux**. You need to install native Ubuntu packages, for example `sudo apt install vlc`.

Comment: Thank you @Melebuis and @ Boris for the advice I'll hook up on some wifi and get them all back.  thanks for the help guys!

Comment: each platform is completely different from each other and can't run other OSes' binaries. Why do you want to run Windows executables when there are already alternatives on Linux?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I just thought to save on data (as we pay through our ears on data in my home country and I dont always have access to wifi networks) and to save time. But reading the comments now I realise it was a silly thought. Im rather new to Linux and still learning.

Comment: In case that you don't have good internet access then you should download the DVD version of Ubuntu, which contains a lot more packages than the minimal or normal version so you don't need to online to get the needed things

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: _Download_ an entire DVD instead of just downloading the packages one wants to install? That's not a way to save on download costs.

Comment: @HenningMakholm apparently finding a free wifi, downloading the whole DVD at once then go home and install is much much cheaper than go on the internet and get each package you want every time. In the dialup era I also have to do something like that, prepare a whole list of things needed to download, write the emails to be ready to sent then go online and do all at once. There are a lot of tools for downloading a bunch of webpages for offline viewing

Comment: @BoristheSpider The programs from Windows _may_ run under Linux using Wine. However, a native package is still the best option.

Answer (score 27):

Windows programs will not run natively on Ubuntu. You would probably be able to run them in [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) (a Windows compatibility layer for Unix-systems), but in most cases, there is also a Linux version. If you're looking for alternative programs simply browsing the software center (search for "Ubuntu Software" in the dash) will get you results, if not, search the web or check out [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/). They have a filter option for Linux programs.

**Be careful fooling around with folders outside your home directory.** Usually you're supposed to install apps using the `apt-get install application-name` or `snap install application-name` command, from the software center, or by downloading and installing .deb files.

But if you need to do something funky in `etc`, just prefix your commands with `sudo` or type the sudo bang bang (`sudo !!`) command directly after you issued a command with insufficient permissions. If don't want to retype the sudo command every time, you can issue `sudo -i` to login as root or `sudo su` to log in as root and stay in your home folder. Doing this will give you administrative rights within that terminal session. After you're finished, type `exit` to log back in with your user account or close the terminal window. But be careful: With great power comes great responsibility. And don't drink and `sudo`.

Also, most programs don't go in the `etc` folder. Use `usr` or `opt`. If you're using wine to run your old windows apps, you will use what is called a virtual C drive - essentially just a folder inside you home directory. Detailed instructions can be found [on their website](https://www.winehq.org/).

Answer (score 6):

Along with the information currently posted here I'd also like to add several things in terms of cross-platform compatibility between Linux and Windows:

- Modern Windows is built off the Windows NT platform (which in turn can run DOS applications, but is entirely different from DOS); Ubuntu/Linux is built off of Unix. You simply can't run **most** Windows applications natively under Ubuntu, and vice versa.
- Both use entirely different rendering APIs - Microsoft uses DirectX (can use OpenGL) while Linux relies on OpenGL (note, this is likely to change with the introduction of Vulkan, which is the cross-platform equivalent of DirectX 12).
- Wine, or **W**ine **i**s **n**ot an **E**mulator, is a compatibility layer that allows some Windows programs to be run in Ubuntu. [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/) has a list of applications with user-submitted reviews for various Windows applications under Wine.
- Wine is limited to DirectX 9 or lower, which means that some applications and games are not supported. Wine also can't make low-level API calls which means that some programs that interface with the hardware **will not work**. (Ex: AutoHotkey).
- Wine is roughly 10-20% slower than native Windows **in most applications**, as well. ***Always look for native Linux alternatives***. Performance is better and you don't have to deal with the pain of switching and transferring between Windows and Ubuntu file structures.

However, files, documents, and videos from Windows that were used by other programs ***can*** be used in Ubuntu, and by Ubuntu applications.

**Please**, don't go around messing with system folders and permissions, especially as you are new to Ubuntu. Commands such as `sudo`, `chmod`, `chown`, `rm`, etc., can do irrevocable damage to your Ubuntu installation. Tread carefully, and you shall reap the benefits of switching to Ubuntu :)

Comment: The last version of Windows that was built on DOS was Windows ME; modern versions of Windows are built on Windows NT.

Comment: Libreoffice in Wine is quite a bit faster than native Linux version — at least when rendering complex charts in Calc (shame on LibO, but this trait was inherited from OOo).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Forgot about that, edited. *facepalm*

Comment: @Ruslan Edited.

Comment: "You **simply can't run Windows applications natively** under Ubuntu..." See also: [Binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) and [How is Mono Magical?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259376/how-is-mono-magical)